# Making a shell in c++, trying to create shell variables

Tags: c++, c, shell, variables, unix

So I have a relatively simple shell, it handles pipes, chdir, redirects and running programs. But I need a way of implementing shell variables like you would have in a normal shell(E.g HELLO=world).

```
int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        string result;
        char * left[128];
        char * right[128];

        cout << "$$ ";
        char command[128];
        cin.getline(command,128);

        if(strlen(command) != 0)
        {
           vector<char*>args;
           char* prog = strtok(command, " ");
           char* tmp = prog;

           while ( tmp != NULL )
           {
              args.push_back( tmp );
              tmp = strtok( NULL, " " );
           }    

           char** argv = new char*[args.size()+1];

           for ( int k = 0; k < args.size(); k++ )
           {
              argv[k] = args[k];
           }

           argv[args.size()] = NULL;

           if ( strcmp( command, "exit" ) == 0 )
           {
              return 0;
           }

           if(!strcmp(prog,"cd"))
           {
              chdir(argv);
           }

           if(prog[0] == '.')
           {        
              std::system(args[0]);
           }
           else
           {
              pid_t kidpid = fork();

              if(kidpid < 0)
              {
                 perror("Could not fork");
                 return -1;
              }
              else if (kidpid == 0)
              {
                 execvp(prog,argv);
              }
              else
              {
                 if(waitpid(kidpid,0,0) <0 )
                 {
                    return -1;
                 }
              }
          }
      }
  }

      return 0;     
   }
```

Here's the shell from the simplest form, the function calls do pretty much what they say.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, the obvious place to start would probably be `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the variables in your shell, you should look into getenv() and setenv() found in stdlib.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setenv.html
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getenv.html

This avoids having to use storage in your C/C++ program with the STL. For example, you can set variables by

```
setenv("variablename", "value", 1);
```

Where the 1 turns on overwrite for the current variable if it exists. So in your example, we would use

```
setenv("HELLO", "world", 1);
```

You can also retrieve the value of the variable by using

```
char *value = getenv("variablename");
```

You do not need to dynamically allocate value.

Note: These values persist for the life of the program that simulates the shell, after which they no longer exist.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between a shell variable and an environment variable. Environment variables are inherited by child processes, while shell variables are not. See `export` in bash.

Answer (score 2):

You need 3 things:

- Parse `FOO=foo` variable assignments in the input lines
- Parse `$FOO` variable references in the input lines, replace with value
- Storage of the variable names and values

There are endless possibilities how to do the latter.

- Single dynamic char array, all variables stored in a single string, with a magic character of your choice separating the entries: `FOO=foo#BAR=baz#SPAM=eggs`. Scales O(n) with the number of entries.
- Dynamic array containing pairs of char pointers for variable names and values. Scales O(n).
- Linked list, where you insert above pairs in a sorted way. Scales O(log n) if you do insertions and lookups with a binary search.
- Binary tree for above pairs, if unbalanced, scales between O(log n) and O(n).
- Hash table. Scales O(1).
- Etc, etc, etc.

With a dynamic array, I mean that you always `realloc` the whole thing upon insertions.

Comment: For storage, a `map<string,string>` from the standard library is a no-brainer choice in C++

Comment: Yes, I admit I never think in C++ :-)